# how to build debuginfo rpm in the kernel 4.19.x

Tags: linux, kernel

I use the command `make rpm-pkg` to build debuginfo rpm for kernel(4.19.1), but it didn't work.so I tried to remove `#%debug_package{null}` in the `scripts/package/mkspec` and add `find_debuginfo.sh xxxx`  to enable debug module，but after I run the command `make rpm-pkg` again, I got the debuginfo rpm but it seems abnormal。 the size of the rpm is around 600k which is obviously not correct.

also i found all the 3.10.x version of kernel has the --with=debuginfo parameter to enable the debug module, which is also not work in 4.19.1 version. so i would like to know whether there is any other approach that build the debuginfo rpm.

Comment: Building rpms is not part of the stock kernel, so you need to specify what distro you are using and where the source is from.

Comment: I download the kernel source code in the centos 7, then  command `make rpm-pkg`

Comment: For CentOS, you install the kernel source rpm, then use rpmbuild.  https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

Comment: @stark modify 3.10.x kernel.spec , then pmbuild in the  4.19.x source code ? 4.19.x kernel.spec don't have the --with=debuginfo parameter

Comment: I understand what you mean， but I don't find the kernel-4.19.1-1.src.rpm

Comment: @TonyY hi, I had the same problem(the kernel-debuginfo rpm is around 600k), how do you solve this problem ?